# How to get id base on value in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to get id value based on value of tag (using jquery and javascript).  
Example: i want value id is "CT107", my input is 30136_02.
Can you help me?
Thanks

```html
<div id="result">
<input type="hidden" id="CT106" value="30136_01">
<input type="hidden" id="CT107" value="30136_02">
<input type="hidden" id="CT108" value="30136_03">
<input type="hidden" id="CT109" value="30136_04">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery, you can do something like this. It selects the input element based on the value of the `value` attribute, and then fetches its ID using `attr` method:

```js
var value = '30136_02';
var input = $(`input[value=${value}]`);

if (input.length) {
  console.log(input.attr('id'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">
  <input type="hidden" id="CT106" value="30136_01">
  <input type="hidden" id="CT107" value="30136_02">
  <input type="hidden" id="CT108" value="30136_03">
  <input type="hidden" id="CT109" value="30136_04">
</div>
```